# laravel project works on localhost but not working on gcloud after deployment

Tags: php, laravel, gcloud

I have a laravel project that works on gcloud , But image uploading function shows an error and the same function works perfectly on localhost .
please help me to fix it , thanks in advance

```php
 $gallery = new Gallery;
 $filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();
 $org_path = '../public/images/gallery/originals/' . $filename;
 $thm_path = '../public/images/gallery/thumbnails/' . $filename;

 $gallery->image     = 'images/gallery/originals/'.$filename;
 $gallery->thumbnail = 'images/gallery/thumbnails/'.$filename;
 $gallery->title     = $request->title;
 $gallery->status    = $request->status;

 if ( ! $gallery->save()) {
    flash('Gallery could not be updated.')->error()->important();
    return redirect()->back()->withInput();
 }

 if (($org_img && $thm_img) == true) {
    Image::make($image)->fit(900, 500, function ($constraint) {
          $constraint->upsize();
    })->save($org_path);
    Image::make($image)->fit(270, 160, function ($constraint) {
        $constraint->upsize();
    })->save($thm_path);
  }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76lwH.png)

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Can't write image data to path (../public/images/gallery/originals/electro.jpg)

Comment: may be permission error ! Check error_log and your file path . Coz file path is always give trouble when move into new env

Comment: I have given permission to the directrories and still shows error

Comment: did you check your symlinks and public directory on google cloud?

Comment: Double check your paths, it looks like you're trying to write to a dir that doesnt exist or has wrong permissions for writing.

Comment: could you please check the error , link of the image is given

Comment: change ../public/images/gallery/originals/electro.jpg to /public/images/gallery/originals/electro.jpg

Comment: Could you please try to change ALL your paths to the following format? 
$org_path = public_path('public/images/gallery/originals/' . $filename); 
I think that should resolve your issue, If you already cross checked that all your folders has read/write permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using relative path **give the actual path**. this will solve the problem.

Comment: ssh into your app 
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance

Go to Terminal.
In terminal
cd.. (will go to $home)
cd.. (will go to root page)
cd var /www/html

Your files will be found here

Comment: actually my app is on app engine

Comment: thank you all for your attention 
i have just solved the problem using gcloud buckets